# what is type of this data?

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, data-science

Please tell me type of train_images? Its nparray?

```
    data_dir = self.data_dir
    fd = open(os.path.join(data_dir, 'train-images-idx3-ubyte'))
    loaded = np.fromfile(file=fd, dtype=np.uint8)
    train_images = loaded[16:].reshape((60000, 28, 28,1)).astype(np.float)
```

Other my question is: How I can convert jpg images of one folder to format of train_images?? I want to make train and test dataset.
Thank you

Comment: `print( type(train_images) )`

Comment: I didn't run this code. Because I don't have that's data

Comment: Stackoverflow is not Forum but Question@Answers portal . You should one question on one page. For other question you should use button `Ask Question`

Comment: I don't know what module to do you use but many of Data Science modules have functions to load image and directly create numpy array. ie. `cv2.imread(filename)`, `matplotlib.pyplot.imread(filename)`, `np.array(imageio.imread(filename))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check type of any object you can use `type()`

```
print( type(train_images) )
```

---

Many modules (not only for Data Science) have function to load image and directly create numpy array or it can be easily converted using `np.array()`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'image.jpg'
```

---

```
import matplotlib.pyplot

img = matplotlib.pyplot.imread(filename)

print(type(img), img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

---

It may need to convert colors BGR to RGB

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(filename)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

print(type(img), img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

---

```
import imageio

img = np.array(imageio.imread(filename))
img = np.array(img)

print(type(img), img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

---

```
import PIL.Image

img = PIL.Image.open(filename)
img = np.array(img)

print(type(img), img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

---

Need to rotate - swap axes

```
import pygame

img = pygame.image.load(filename)
img = pygame.surfarray.array3d(img)
img = img.swapaxes(0, 1)

print(type(img), img.shape)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

---

```
import skimage

img = skimage.io.imread(filename)

print(type(img), img.shape)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

---

```
import scipy.misc

img = scipy.misc.imread(filename)

print('scipy:', type(img), img.shape)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

It loads image but it shows warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: `imread` is deprecated!
`imread` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
Use ``imageio.imread`` instead.
```

---

It has to be converted from `PIL.Image` to `numpy.array`

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img

img = load_img(filename)
img = np.array(img)

print('keras:', type(img), img.shape)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```